# The prefix of url in a website

Tags: html

I'm confused with a status.

I download the page of http:// tukaani.org/xz/format.html and wants to follow the href in the html, however, **link like 
        < a  href="xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt"> 
point to http:// tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt instead of http:// tukaani.org/xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt'.**

How could I get the prefix of url, it is not hostname, or base, I cannot find any useful info in the headers, there is no string like 'http:// tukaani.org/xz/' in the header. But any browser knows the link.

What is the internal mechanism. How can I use wget,curl or perl to get the prefix 'http:// tukaani.org/xz/' in 'http:// tukaani.org/xz/format.html'?

Comment: http is the protocol other options are file:// ftp:// and https:// However there's an extreme lack of clarity in your question.

Comment: I modified my question, the < a href="xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt"> didn't appear if I didn't put space between < and a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens here is that there are two kind of links: absolute or relative.

The one you mention is relative, but relative to what? The answer is: relative to the current page url, so since you are visiting `http://example.com/xz/format.html` the base url is `http://example.com/xz/`

If you were visiting `http://example.com/xz/another-sublevel/foo.html` then the "base" would be `http://example.com/xz/another-sublevel/`

As you may have noticed it works like a folder/file structure, so with relative links you start from the current url's "folder" to build the url.

An absolute link would start with `/` (the so called "root" of the folder tree structure) so if you had `<a href="/xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt">`, on any page you would go to `http://example.com/xz-file-format-1.0.4.txt`